# Convert CensusWard codes to Google Maps (UK)

Tags: google-maps, census, united-kingdom

The UK's Office for National Statistics uses Census Ward codes for some of its data.

For instance, this file - https://www.ons.gov.uk/visualisations/dvc479/map/data/data.xls - has life expectancy by ward.

Example codes:

```
E36000489 Bathavon North
E36000492 Bathwick
```

What's the best way to turn these codes into a map showing the border of the area?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to join them to the [Ward Boundaries](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/search?collection=Dataset&sort=name&tags=all(BDY_CMWD%2CDEC_2011)) on the Open Geography Portal.